# How to update records in a Postgres table with Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have basic django app that returns data from Postgres tables in an AWS RDS instance. 
I have a few endpoint which relate to few tables in the RDS.

What I want to do is update records in table. If the record exists it should be updated, if it does not exist then nothing should happen Orit should throw an error.

This is my models.py file -

```
from django.db import models

class Campaigns(models.Model):
    id_campaign = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    id_taste_cluster = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to update the *status* field in this table where status = ' '.

This is my serialiser file -

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Campaigns

class Campaigns_1_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaigns
        fields = ('id_campaign', 'status', 'id_taste_cluster')
```

This is my views file -

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Campaigns
from .serializers import Campaigns_1_Serializer

class UpdateView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.DATA
        queryset = Campaigns.objects.filter(status='')
        serializer = Campaigns_1_Serializer(queryset, data=data, many=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to give the users the option to update only those campaigns for which the status is '  '(blank).

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your update method :

```
#your imports
from rest_framework import serializers

class YourModelViewset(ModelViewSet):
     #your code

     def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           instance = self.get_object()
           # checks if the object staus is empty
           If object.status == "" or object.status is None :
               raise serializers.ValidationError("your error message")
           return super(YourModelViewset, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```